# Amazon MWS get product parent category

Tags: ruby, amazon-mws

When I fetch data for the product i.e :

```
get_matching_product_for_id('UPC', '887439784189')
```

And part of the response is :

```
"SalesRankings"=>
  {"SalesRank"=>
    {"ProductCategoryId"=>"apparel_display_on_website", "Rank"=>"6257"}}}
```

How do I associate `apparel_display_on_website` to category `Clothing`. Do I need to invoke another api method?

Comment: When you say "associate" you mean "translate" and not "assign", right?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `ProductGroup` is identified in the `GetMatchingProductForId` response as an `ItemAttribute`. Is that what you're looking for?

From the [docs](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetMatchingProductForId.html), edited for brevity:

```
...
<Product>
    ...
    <AttributeSets>
        <ns2:ItemAttributes xml:lang="en-US">
            ...
            <ns2:ProductGroup>Book</ns2:ProductGroup>
            ...
        </ns2:ItemAttributes>
    </AttributeSets>
    ...
</Product>
...
```

If you want all the `ProductCategories`, you can use `GetProductCategoriesForSKU` or `GetProductCategoriesForASIN`, which will respond with very detailed category info (including all of the category hierarchy, example [here](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetProductCategoriesForSKU.html)).